# Centos kernel .config file. Where can I find it?

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, configuration

I am rebuilding a custom kernel. I am on Windows, what is the quickest way to grab the `.config` file for the CentOS RHEL linux kernel (for `make oldconfig`). I can't find it preinstalled in the Linux system (e.g. no /proc/config.gz) I am assuming it is in a source RPM somewhere. Do you have a link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `/boot/config-$(uname -r)`.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find it preinstalled in the Linux system (e.g. no
>   `/proc/config.gz`)

Because you haven't enabled [`CONFIG_IKCONFIG`](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/IKCONFIG.html) and [`CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC`](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/IKCONFIG_PROC.html). The Linux kernel configuration is also found in the kernel source `/usr/src/linux/.config` (in CentOS, it is `/usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)-$(uname -m)/.config`).